# 'this' in JavaScript behaves differently in node and chrome console

Tags: javascript

running the same code in different environments produces different results[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RqJY.png)

try running the code below in chrome console and on node js, the first produces `snehal` `snehal` and the other `undefined` `undefined`

```
this.name = "snehal";

function meme() {
  console.log(this.name);
  function mem() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
  mem();
}

meme();
```

The basic idea about `this` in JavaScript is that it points/refers to the object that contains it, so in the chrome console we can expect the inner mem function `this` to be === to the meme function this, but the same is not consistent in the node environment.

Comment: `this` refers to the object that contains the function means that the function `obj.foo = function () { console.log(this) }` will print `String(obj)`. By default, every function is attached to the global object which is `window` in the browser and `global` in NodeJs. In both cases `this.name = "shehal"` should result in attaching the property `name` to the global object and `this.name` inside the two function should return "shehal". Strange! Can you provide more context for the browser code?

Comment: _“`this` […] points/refers to the object that contains [the function]”_ is wrong. See [How does the "this" keyword work?](/q/3127429/4642212). @MarcelloDelBuono `console.log` does not invoke `String` or any `toString` method. The duplicate link has been edited. This behavior has already been explained. The reason is that `this` isn’t `global` in the top scope of a Node.js module. Apart from that, e.g. in functions called without base reference, or by simply using `globalThis` instead, it is.